# Do some ascii characters take up more than 1 byte of memory?

Tags: java, file, memory, text, binary

I have a piece of code like this:

```
String a="10100101010101001010101001....."
for(int i=0;i<a.length()-8;i+=8){
            String k=a.substring(i,i+8);
            int num=Integer.parseInt(k,2);
            char o=(char)(num);
            out.print(o);//print to file
}
```

Bassically, we print out the ascii characters into a txt file after recieving a binary string.
The number of times this loop runs and the number of characters printed is ~1100.
However, inspecting the filesize of this txt file, it is around 1700 bytes. How does this make sense and why could this be happening? 
However, if I attempt to print characters into a txt file that are "normal" (a-z, 0-9, etc..) It seems to take up the same amount of bytes as characters (1 byte = 1 ascii character = 8 bits).

Somehow, when I print those "weirder" ascii characters, more memory is used. Is there a way to work around this issue? (print exactly the number of characters)

Comment: Java `Strings` and characters aren't held in ASCII. they are held in UTF-16, and `OutputWriter` uses a UTF encoding as well, not necessarily ASCII. One would have to know your platform and how `out` was constructed to be more precise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**ASCII**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters only take up 1 byte, unless you're encoding in something like [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), but that's very rare.

However, *ASCII* only defines characters 0-127. Anything above that is not ASCII, but [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (or [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII), but that's like 100+ different "standards").

If the characters 128 and above use multiple bytes, it would seem you're encoding the file in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is generally a good idea.

If you only use e.g. Western Latin characters, you can alternatively encode the file in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) / [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which will make all characters use only 1 byte, but any unsupported characters will be converted to a `?`.